# Regex not working on input attr 'pattern'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex: `^[a-z]{4}\d{1}[a-z]{7}`
... and I want to test it against this string: **CELF5QiOFFER**

It works fine in JS, as well as on various online regex testers, but I can't make it working on the 'pattern' attr of input in html:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-z]{4}\d{1}[a-z]{7}" name="formName" />
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nR6yg/425/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a different pattern there. This one you posted will work. You just need `pattern="[a-z]{4}\d[a-z]{7}"`. What are the actual requirements? Match a string that starts with 4 lowercase ASCII, then has 1 digit, and ends with 7 lowercase ASCII letters? Please confirm.

Comment: This is still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/nR6yg/428/

Comment: "Not working" does not make any sense. What are the *requirements*? Something works or does not work ONLY as per the requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew try using `pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d[a-zA-Z]{7}$"`

Comment: @andreim: Sure `[a-zA-Z]` will allow matching uppercase letters, too. Still, the anchors are not necessary here. `pattern` regex is anchored by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes because you need upper and lowercase characters, as in `CELF5QiOFFER`. Notice the lowercase `i`.

Comment: @andreim: OP did not even mention if that string must match or must not match. Besides, *It works fine in JS* - where is the JS code where it works? It would not work in JS.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes :) guessing mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{7}" name="formName" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

The reason for it not working properly was that you were looking for lower case letters, i.e. case sensitive. The other reason was that for some reason you had `[]` around the regex statement?

Here's an updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nR6yg/430/) with it working

Comment: You don't need `^`